# How do you calculate if a number is a multiple of another number(well sort of)

Tags: c#, sql

pls, I HAVE A NUMBER  say 9 and i want to find how to create a program to check if a number b is maybe 21(ie 9+12) or 33(ie 9 + 24) or 45(9 + 36) and so on. Can i get it in C# or SQL

Comment: er... those aren't multiples...? That is just addition... I'm really unclear what you want to do here, since (if we ignore Int32 range overflow for simplicity) there is **always** a set of integers that will satisfy that, and finding them is just basic arithmetic. If you mean a *[primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)*, then it becomes more interesting.

Comment: Only multiple I see is that the example has the number `b` as a multiple of 12 in each step, is that coincidence or is it relevant to your question?

Comment: Actually u are right, they are just additions. But i want to find out how to test if b is any of those

Comment: b *will* always exist. b = number + 9

Answer (score 8):

With the clarification, it looks like you want to find whether there is an integer `x` for which (in math terms, not code)

```
b = 9 + 12x
```

is true; so you want to know whether `b-9` is some multiple of `12`; which is easy:

```
bool isMatch = ((b - 9) % 12) == 0;
```

and if you want to know which `x`:

```
int x = (b - 9) / 12;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but I think you're looking for the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). `21 % 12 = 9`, `33 % 12 = 9`, `45 % 12 = 9`.

In C# and SQL this is just `%`, and it is used like an arithmetic operator (+, -, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got three variables and than the solution will be like this:

```
var a = 9;
var b = 12;
var c = 21;

var isInRange = IsInRange(c, a, b);

private bool IsInRange(int input, int offset, int multiple){
    return ((input - offset) % multiple) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract your original number (in this case 9) from the number B, and then see if B % 12 is different from zero.